# Leslie matrix: why is it enough to just evaluate det$(A-λI)$ to tell if the population grows or decays?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There is a $3\times3$ Leslie matrix and we are told to evaluate $\det(A—λI)$ to tell if the population grows or decays when $λ=1$;

$λ=1,$ the population is stable
when evaluating $\det(A—λI) = 1/48 \gt 0$ 
which implies that the real eigenvalues must be either less than 1 (population decays) or greater than $1$ (population grows)

How do I conclude if the population grows or decays by just looking at $p(λ) = \det(A—λI) = 1/48 > 0$?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: So, what’s a Leslie matrix?

Comment: the Leslie Matrix is [1/2 0 1; 1/2 3/4 0; 0 1/6 1/2]

Comment: Hint: the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so its sign can tell you the parity (even vs odd) of the number of negative eigenvalues. Combine that with knowing the total number of eigenvalues to get what you need.

Comment: I don’t really care about the specific matrix you’re working with. What *is* a Leslie matrix, what does $\lambda$ represent in your question and how are they related?

Comment: @amd, if you want to know more about what the terms mean then just google.  Lambda represents a freaking eigenvalue in Linear Algebra; this is not Physics.  The information given in my post is enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Ian thank you.

Comment: I solved it.  Thanks all.

Comment: @Erint See [How to Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/265466) if you’re planning to come back to this site again for more help. It’s rather presumtuous of you to ask for people to spend their own time to help you and then force them to figure out what your terms and symbols mean when you could take a few moments of your own apparently precious time to provide context for your question. Abusive and rude answers don’t help your case.